# No platform higher than Oreo (8.1) is available Android SDK

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-sdk-manager

I'm using both VS17 & VS19, I've opened the Android SDK (as administrator after it didn't install otherwise) and I don't have platforms higher than 27:
[image]

I've tried to install all the relevant Build Tools via the Tools tab but the max platform version is still 27.

Comment: try clicking the cog wheel and change the repository to the google one in this window

Comment: both are the same..

Comment: Have you tried uninstall/reinstall "Mobile development in .NET" in vs installer "modify"? or doing a VS repair in VS installer? Which version of VS2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, have a check with the visual studio version whether is the latest version. Such as Visual Studio 2019 is `16.8.3` .And check the **Tools** of **SDK Manager** whether install the relative latest version of **Android SDK Build Tools** :

[image]

**Second**, in the latest version of VS 2019, you could choose choose **Full List** as follows:

[image]

**Last**, you could have a check with network whether can connect to the server of Andoid SDK well.

Comment: Thank you, the project is VS17 and not VS19. I do have Android 10 when I open the Android SDK from the VS19 application but not when I open it via the VS17, does VS17 support only up to Android 8?

Comment: @SagiLow No, VS 2017 also supports Android 9 but will not support Android 10. Visual Studio 2019 is recommended. If you are using Visual Studio 2017, on Windows update to Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 or later. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/pie#requirements